# Trying to integrate google pay to my android app

Tags: android, google-pay

I am trying to integrate google pay to my android app. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/google-pay-integration-android/) that I found,but when I run my code I keep getting this error `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.sqill, PID: 12555
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=upi://pay?pa=your-merchant-vpa@xxx&pn=your-merchant-name&mc=your-merchant-code&tr=your-transaction-ref-id&tn=your-transaction-note&am=your-order-amount&cu=INR pkg=com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user }`

Here is my code so far. Thanks in advance

//PaymentPageActivity.java

```
 Button pay_button;
    final int UPI_PAYMENT=0;
    Integer amount=5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment_page);

        pay_button=findViewById(R.id.pay);

        //startActivity

        pay_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                payUsingUpi();


            }
        });


    }

    private void payUsingUpi() {

        Uri uri =
                new Uri.Builder()
                        .scheme("upi")
                        .authority("pay")
                        .appendQueryParameter("pa", "your-merchant-vpa@xxx")
                        .appendQueryParameter("pn", "your-merchant-name")
                        .appendQueryParameter("mc", "your-merchant-code")
                        .appendQueryParameter("tr", "your-transaction-ref-id")
                        .appendQueryParameter("tn", "your-transaction-note")
                        .appendQueryParameter("am","$5.00")
                        .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR").build();

        String GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android";
        int GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.setPackage(GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME);
       startActivityForResult(intent, GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be using the wrong package name. According to the following [example](https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/android/in-app-payments):

```java
String GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user";
int GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE = 123;

Uri uri =
    new Uri.Builder()
        .scheme("upi")
        .authority("pay")
        .appendQueryParameter("pa", "your-merchant-vpa@xxx")
        .appendQueryParameter("pn", "your-merchant-name")
        .appendQueryParameter("mc", "your-merchant-code")
        .appendQueryParameter("tr", "your-transaction-ref-id")
        .appendQueryParameter("tn", "your-transaction-note")
        .appendQueryParameter("am", "your-order-amount")
        .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
        .appendQueryParameter("url", "your-transaction-url")
        .build();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
intent.setPackage(GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Package name should be `com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user`.

Comment: Please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/q/76988284