# Payment through Google Pay sometimes succeeds sometimes fails using UPI Intent in Android Studio [business UPI ID]

Tags: java, android, payment-gateway, google-pay, upi

I am using this library ([Library link](https://github.com/samudraganguly/upi)) to create a UPI intent. This library supports both payment intent and QR code generation. Now, payment through PhonePe succeeds but payment through GooglePay sometimes succeeds and sometimes fails (when done through intent). Payment through PhonePe always succeeds (both using Intent and QR).

This is what I am trying to do.

MainActivity.java

```
    btn1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        try {
            UPI upi = UPI.getInstance();
            Intent payIntent = upi.getPaymentIntent(UPI_ID, NAME, "1", "INR", "Test", "", MERCHANT_CODE, UPI.ALL_APPS);
            launcher.launch(payIntent);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(new QRFragment(), "QR").commit();
    });
```

QRFragment.java

```
    UPI upi = UPI.getInstance();
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = upi.getQR(UPI_ID, NAME, "1", "INR", "Test", "", MERCHANT_CODE, 512);
        img = view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Note**: The recipient UPI ID is a **business UPI ID**.

Edited: The merchant has only PhonePe and PayTM merchant ID (no Google Pay). Can it be a problem?

Comment: You can Contact to Customer Support As they can help you with this case. As far **AS MY experience Your code seems correct**. So The Last Option is left to contact customer support [here](https://developers.google.com/business-communications/business-messages/support/contact) you can get info how to get customer support.
You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239372/google-pay-upi-integration-not-working-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1) stack overflow question and [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61417463/trying-to-integrate-google-pay-to-my-android-app